# Google Map won't display markers

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

Started working with Android Studio, trying to display a Google Map in a fragment. The maps displays fine and I'm able to zoom/move the map around, but my markers will not display.

Here is my MapsActivity (HomePageMapsActivity.java):

```
public class HomePageMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so, and the map has not already been instantiated.
 * If not installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will prompt user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers, lines, listeners, or move the camera.
 * Only call once and when sure {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(33, -84)).title("Atlanta"));
}

}
```

The xml (activity_home_page_maps.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
tools:context="net.datanetics.campusresponseapp.HomePageMapsActivity" />
```

The home page xml (activity_home_page):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/HomePageMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        tools:context=".HomePageMapsActivity"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#3498DB"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EmergencyButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"              
            android:background="#C1392B"
            android:text="Emergency"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using the correct lat/lng ? If yes, I think the marker is already there but you need to zoom to that point to show the marker.

Comment: @ProkashSarkar Would the marker not be visible at any zoom level? The current LatLng would place the cursor in the middle of Georgie, but there are no markers in that area.

Comment: @Jason Any particular reason you are calling this method setUpMapIfNeeded() twice ?

Comment: @Soham Most of the code present in the Java file was generated by Android Studio when I created the fragment. The only thing I've changed is the LatLng for the marker.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, your `GoogleMap` is not null? Try to get map asynchronously:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment fragMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page_maps);

        fragMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragMap.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
        if (map != null) {
            mMap = map;
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes a crash. Is there a particular way to diagnose what the cause is?

Comment: @Jason Yes, see your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) You are trying to use the map too early. You need to have the view
first, so your code should be in onCreateView() not onCreate().
**Correction**: onCreateView() applies to fragments, not activities.
The app I used to test this used a Fragment to hold the map, not a
FragmentActivity.

2) I found I needed to prod the initialization of the map layers by
calling mMapView.onCreate() and mMapView.onResume() explicitly. See
also [JoelLipman.com](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/google/android-o-s/app-development/745-android-os-add-googlemap-as-fragment.html).

```
public class HomePageMaps extends SupportMapFragment {
  private View mView;
  private View mMapView;
  private GoogleMap mMap;

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle state) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, group, state);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_page_maps, group, false);
    mMapView= (MapView)mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(state);
    mMapView.onResume();
    mMap= mMapView.getMap();
    mapUpdate();
    return (mView);
  }

  private void mapUpdate() {
    LatLng myLoc= new LatLng(33,-84);
    MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions();
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLoc, 15));
    mMap.addMarker(opt.position(myLoc).title("Me"));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking over your provided link now to see if that answers my questions. The code in your original post brings back three errors, all 'cannot find symbol method' for onCreate(Bundle), onResume(), getMap().

Comment: That is because I am embedding the map in a Fragment, your code embeds it in an Activity. I tried removing the calls to mMapView.onCreate() and mMapView.onResume() and the map no longer worked properly. Also note that this creates the map synchronously. If it create the map asynchronously as suggested in the other answer, you shouldn't need to worry about calling down to the child views. Try just adding the calls to mMapView.onCreate() and mMapView.onResume() to your onCreate() code.

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue change this line

```
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(33, -84)).title("Atlanta"));
```

to

```
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(33.7550,84.3900)).title("Atlanta"));
```

you have to pass the `double` value in lat and lng.

Comment: I switched out the lines you suggested but a marker is not showing on the map.

Comment: First to tell me your will able to seen map or not?

Comment: I am able to see the map. I can move around and pinch to zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I found my "FirstMap" project, hope it helps. You will want to 
move your map into a fragment sooner rather than later.

`MapsActivity.java`

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private PageMap mPageMap;

  public interface IAction {
    boolean onClick(int BtnID);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageMap= new PageMap();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void onClick(View Ctrl) {
    int BtnID= Ctrl.getId();
    switch(BtnID) {
      case R.id.MainBtn_Map:  ShowMap(); break;
      default:                mPageMap.onClick(BtnID);
    }
  }

  private void ShowMap() {
    LoadPage(mPageMap);
  }

  public void LoadPage(Fragment NewPage) {
    FragmentManager Mgr= getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction Action= Mgr.beginTransaction();
    Action.replace(R.id.Main_FragmentContainer,NewPage);
    Action.show(NewPage);
    Action.commit();
  }
}
```

`res/layout/activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/MainBtn_Map"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Load Map"
  />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Main_FragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
  >

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`PageMap.java`

```
public class PageMap extends SupportMapFragment implements MapsActivity.IAction {
  private FragmentActivity mActivity;
  private MapView mMapView;
  private GoogleMap mMap;

  @Override public void onAttach(Activity parent) {
    mActivity= (FragmentActivity)parent;
    super.onAttach(parent);
  }

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle instance) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater,group,instance);
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_map,group,false);
    mMapView= (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(instance);
    mMapView.onResume();
    mMap= mMapView.getMap();
    return(view);
  }

  public boolean onClick(int BtnID) {
    switch(BtnID) {
      case R.id.PageMap_BtnUpdate:         return (Update());
    }
    return (false);
  }

  private boolean Update() {
    setUpMap();
    return(true);
  }

  private void setUpMap() {
    if(mMap!=null) {
      LatLng loc = new LatLng(-34, 151);
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Marker"));
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 15));
    }
  }
}
//EOF: PAGEMAP.JAVA
```

`res/layout/page_map.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/PageMap_BtnUpdate"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Update"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```